# counter resets itself when the user logs out

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the `timeTo` jquery library to display a counter and call a function when that counter expires. This happens after 24 hours. When the price is claimed the counter resets to allow another 24 hours. The code is below, but the problem I have is that the counter resets itself when the user logs out:

```
<div id="countdown-1"></div>
<div class="clock"></div>
<div class="clock"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.timeTo.js"></script>
<script>
    /**
     * Set timer countdown in seconds with callback
     */
    $('#countdown-1').timeTo(86300, function(){
        $('#countdown-1').timeTo('reset');
    });

    function getRelativeDate(days, hours, minutes){
        var date = new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 60000 /* milisec */ * 60 /* minutes */ * 24 /* hours */ * days /* days */);

        date.setHours(hours || 0);
        date.setMinutes(minutes || 0);
        date.setSeconds(0);

        return date;
    }
</script>
```

How can I make it always run for every user whether that user is logged in or logged out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the current time left in your counter to the current time (to get the end date/time) and then use AJAX to store the end date/time in a database.